# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USE' error while creating database from Script

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlcommand

I am developing a multi tenant application so I need to create database from code for every new client. I have generated script of my schema from SSMS "Generate Script" utility, then I tried the following:

```
public static void CreateIfNotExist(string path) // the path where the script for creating database is located
{
    var db = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["dbName"].ToString();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; uid=sa; pwd=password;"))
    {
        con.Open();

        var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(path);
        var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
        foreach (var item in str.Elements())
        {
             var query = "CREATE DATABASE " + db + Environment.NewLine +  "GO" + Environment.NewLine + "USE " + db + Environment.NewLine + "GO" + Environment.NewLine;
             var scriptToRun = File.ReadAllText(item.Value);
             query += scriptToRun;

             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
             try
             {
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
             }
        }

    }
}
```

And my script is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACOD](
    [id] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [serial] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ACOD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGZH](
    [id] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [number] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AGZH] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

This is just a portion of script. In actual, I have 100+ tables with every table have more than 50 columns.

Now when I use the C# code written above it gave me the following exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'USE'. Database 'databaseName' does not
>   exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

But when I get the script from text visualizer in Visual Studio and execute it in SSMS, it runs successfully and created the new database name.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GO` is not a legal command in T-SQL.

This command is handled by whatever program that you edit your script in, such as SQL Server Management Studio and is used as a delimiter to separate your big query into multiple smaller ones.

You cannot send the `GO` command to SQL Server, or you will get that error.

So basically you should use the `GO` commands to separate your query and execute only the bits inbetween, one bit at a time.

Here is the [documentation of GO (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

Comment: THANKS. It worked. I segregated the command. First I only executed CREATE DATABASE command and then the remaining as another command. Moreover I remove all 'GO' commands from script.
THANKS A Lot. I really pulled my hair over this.